# Change Shift+Backspace to be a back-delete rather than a forward-delete

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

On a Mac, if you hold shift and press the backspace key, it performs a forward-delete (the same as pressing "delete" on a non-Mac keyboard). Is there any way to change this to just be a regular backspace?

Comment: Just to be clear, "don't hold shift" isn't really what I'm looking for...

Comment: I'm dying of curiosity, why would you want this?

Comment: when programming. Say I'm typing `Entity.DELETED` but I get to `Entity.DELTE..` to fix the mistake, you have to release shift and then press it again afterwards. I know it sounds silly, but it's a real PITA when shift-backspace deletes the line-ending and then starts deleting other things you didn't want.

Comment: What keyboard are you using? On my MacBook to get a forward delete I need to hold Fn-delete. That is, typically it is ⌫ but with Fn I get ⌦. Are you saying that ⇧⌫ gets you ⌦?

Comment: @fideli "Are you saying that ⇧⌫ gets you ⌦?" exactly. This happens with my external Windows keyboard, as well as the built-in MacBook keyboard.

Comment: What keyboard layout (in System Preferences, Language & Text, Input Sources) is this? It's not British, US, US Extended or US International (or German for that matter). All of those require fn to be pressed for a forward-delete.

Comment: @Daniel: It is US.

Comment: @nickf: Does the keyboard viewer (see my answer) also show that Shift turns backspace into delete? Also see my third paragraph, does it happen in all applications or just your editor?

Comment: @Daniel - see my answer below. I'm quite clearly an idiot today. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm stupid.

I have DoubleCommand installed, and I, for some reason, enabled the "shift+delete acts as forward delete" command. Apologies.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so the question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your keyboard layout in `System Preferences`, `Language and Text`, `Input Sources`. The Keyboard Viewer, accessible from the menubar item you can enable in that same preference pane enables you to preview keyboard layouts you temporarily select via the same menubar item. You just need to check them in the list to enable them.

You can also use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele) to create your own custom keyboard layout.

This can also be a custom command in your programming editor. IDEs often create additional shortcuts that alleviate the sometimes painfully lame input/shortcut options integrated in the system. Check `TextEdit.app` if it behaves the same, only then is it layout-related.